# Turn static array search into an observable search

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5, angularfire2

I have an question I cant figure it out..

I have this function which works fine on my static array but now I want to turn this into a search in my obseravble.

This is my searchbar in home.html:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchKey" [formControl]="searchControl" (ionInput)="onInput($event)" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

And here is the home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {

   searchControl: FormControl;
   searching: any = false;
   restaurantsList: Observable<any[]>;

   constructor(){
       this.restaurantsList = this.restaurantService.getRestaurantList();
       this.searchControl = new FormControl();
   }      

   ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {  
         this.searching = false;
         this.setFilteredItems();
     });
    }
    setFilteredItems(){
       this.restaurantService.filterRestaurants(this.searchKey).subscribe(
           foundRestaurant => this.restaurantsList = foundRestaurant
       )

       console.log(this.restaurantService.filterRestaurants(this.searchKey));
     }

     onInput(event) {
        this.searching = true;
     }
```

And this is the restaurant-service.ts:

```
export class RestaurantService {

  restaurantsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  restaurantsList: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
      public afDb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
      this.restaurantsRef = afDb.list('/restaurants');
      this.restaurantsList = this.restaurantsRef.valueChanges();
  }

   getRestaurantList() {
      return this.restaurantsList;
   }

    filterRestaurants(searchKey: string) {
       let key: string = searchKey.toUpperCase();

       return this.restaurantsList.map(
           restaurantsList => restaurantsList.filter(
              restaurant => [
                restaurant.title.toUpperCase(),
                restaurant.address.toUpperCase(),
                restaurant.city.toUpperCase(),
                restaurant.description.toUpperCase()
            ].join(' ').indexOf(key) > -1)
       );
    }
}
```

But in the `setFilteredItems()` method the ide says on `this.restaurantList`:
`Type boolean is not assignable to type Observable<any[]>`

Does anyone know the solution to change the restaurantList to the filteredItems?

FYI I followed this tutorial: [LINK](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.restaurantService.filterRestaurants` returns an `Observable` and you're subscribing to it's result and inside subscribe method you're trying to assign the result to another `Observable`.

If you want to subscribe on observable's result and update the array of restauraunts then your `restaurantsList` should be an array:

```
class HomePage {
   restaurantsList: any[];
```

And all the code should work fine.

## _______________________________________________

Or if you want to update your observable with a new observable
then you should not do it in subscribe method

```
setFilteredItems(){
    this.restaurantsList = this.restaurantService.filterRestaurants(this.searchKey);
}
```

and then in html use async pipe to subscribe to this Observable and render the list of it's values (here I also use json pipe for debug)

```
{{restaurantsList | async | json}}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for you answer, will check it but isn't it better to declare the this.restaurantsList as a  behaviour subject here?

Comment: @Sreinieren I don't think so, cause you don't expect to change the restaurantsList anywhere, you only interested in filtering this list. Your firebase is the source of truth here and you should update the list only via db.

Comment: If I try this it says type Observable<any[]> is not assignable to type any[] property length is missing the type Observable

Comment: @Sreinieren Are you trying to copy all of the suggestions? Cause I suggested 2 ways that should depend on what you're trying to achieve. Either 1st code block or 2nd + 3rd

Comment: Oh lol I didn't saw that, what would you suggest to store it in a array or a new observable?

Comment: I think 2nd option is better cause you can save on `Observable` unsubscription management it will be done automatically with **async** pipe for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167927/discussion-between-sreinieren-and-evgeniy-malyutin).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return of `filterRestaurants`, it's a boolean. You define the property of `restaurantsList` to be an Observable. You need to convert the result of `filterRestaurants` into an Observable.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const filtered: Observable<boolean> = Observable.of( 
    this.restaurantService.filterRestaurants(this.searchKey)
);


filtered.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: How do I use this in my case?

Comment: Could you help me out? because when I try to declare the const it also says that Observable<observable<boolean>> is not assignable to type Observable<boolean>

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be syntactical mistake for me. Here is improvised version and correct searching check by `key`

```
filterRestaurants(searchKey: string) {
    //below line isn't needed at all.
    //this.restaurantsList.subscribe()
    let key: string = searchKey.toUpperCase();
    //returns Observable
    return this.restaurantsList.map(
       restaurantsList => {
         restaurantsList.filter(
           let result = restaurant => [
              restaurant.title.toUpperCase(),
              restaurant.address.toUpperCase(),
              restaurant.city.toUpperCase(),
              restaurant.description.toUpperCase()
           ].join(' ').indexOf(key) > -1
          );
          return Observable.of(result);
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: the `setFilteredItems()` when I am trying to assign the result to this.restaurantList, My ide says type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'

Comment: @Sreinieren Can you send me the screen shot of the same?

Comment: @Sreinieren I want to see whole code, can you update the question?

Comment: @pankajparker updated it this it he whole code for the search

Comment: It returns me the found restaurant when I log it but how do I update this.restaurantList

Comment: With a BehaviorSubject?